# not able to fetch Address using Geocoder in my physical device where as its running fine in my emulaor

Tags: android-studio

### Not working on physical but working fine on emulator

*As i'm calling it in place auto complete and iv used marker dragged listener and its working fine in emulator and its fetching proper address and its details  also* its saying that address list=null when i run in my physical device but in emulator its giving correct result. i have implemented all request,permission

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        List<android.location.Address> addresses=null;
        geocoder=new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        LatLng ll=marker.getPosition();

        try {
            addresses =geocoder.getFromLocation(ll.latitude,ll.longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size()>0&&addresses!=null){


                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);

                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

                }Log.d("RESULT",strReturnedAddress.toString());
                marker.setSnippet(returnedAddress.getLocale().toString());
                pickupAutocomplete.setText(returnedAddress.getLocality().toUpperCase());

            }
            else {
                Log.d("NO-RESULT","NO-RESULT");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("NO-RESULT","NO-RESULT");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: please any one suggest best answer iv searched all over to find its solution

Comment: Try with restarting the device. I have gone through this. :)